# htaccess LimitInternalRecursion error

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

my htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    # Handle Authorization MemberHeader
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]
    
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L,QSA]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

can some one help me to solve this  prob

Comment: You need to give more information... what URL(s) are you requesting? What are you expecting to happen? Where is this `.htaccess` file located? What is your file structure? Do you have other `.htaccess` file(s) - perhaps in the `/public` subdirectory? Something that is immediately strange with the config you've posted is that you are rewriting all requests to a `/public` subdirectory (3rd rule) _before_ attempting to route the request to a front-controller (last rule) in the root?!

Comment: (If you are rewriting requests to a subdirectory then I would expect you to have another `.htaccess` file in that subdirectory that contains the front-controller pattern.) _Aside:_ "LimitInternalRecursion error" - That is not the error, that is just the default suggestion as to a "fix" (but rarely is that the fix). You basically have an endless rewrite loop.